# Deployment failed/ArchitectureNotSupportedBySharedRuntime when deploying App to physical phone

Tags: deployment, xamarin.android, architecture

I have created a Blank Xamarin App in Visual Studio 2017.
I have installed all those components:

**Xamarin.Android

Android SDK

Android NDK (x64)

GTK#

Xamarin Studio

Xamarin for Visual Studio**

Now I try to deploy this App as a test to my physical mobile phone:

- I have enabled Developer Mode in the mobile.
- Phone Android Version: 8.0
- When I connect the USB,  a choice is shown where Debug arrow is: "alps X27 (Android 4.4 - API 19)"

[image]

X27 is the name of my phone and it seems that the API Level is 19 as it shows up automatically.

In the image as seen I have choosed the below settings:
Minimum Android version: Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)
Target Android version: Android 8.0 (API Level 26 - Oreo)

---

**THE ERROR MESSAGE I GET WHEN F5 (Deploy to my mobile) is:**
Deployment failed/ArchitectureNotSupportedBySharedRuntime

What is causing this error?

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0000:  Deployment failed
Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: ArchitectureNotSupportedBySharedRuntime
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__101.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__99.MoveNext()            0*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after a lot of just trying. The below image shows the settings that worked for me in the Properties of the solution:

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark you reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.